# How to change color of the buttons within UIImagePickerController when taking a photo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

For iOS 7 and iOS 8, I'm trying to to change the button color to transparent for the front/back, cancel, and camera button within a UIImagePickerController view. I've tried setting the tintColor, navigationBar tint color, and some appearance settings.

Here's my best guess of how to do it - using Xamarin/Monotouch but an answer in native code works fine:

```
UIButton.AppearanceWhenContainedIn (typeof(UIImagePickerController)).TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

I've also tried changing the navigation bar options:

```
var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
imagePicker.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
imagePicker.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
imagePicker.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
imagePicker.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

No effect. Here's an example of it not working. (trying to make the green areas transparent)

[image]

What's the best way to make the background of the buttons transparent? Thanks!

Comment: Are those Xcode's template buttons or are you using custom ones?

Comment: Just the standard UIImagePickerController. Thanks for the help, I must be missing something simple.

Comment: I don't think that the navigationBar property has any effect on the UIImagePickerController controls. if I'm not mistaken, the background should be transparent as default. are you explicitly changing the colours somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Yes, we're setting tint colors etc using the Appearance classes. I'd like to exclude these controls from the appearance settings, but I haven't been able to figure out what type to exclude. Any idea? Contemplating looping through all subviews etc...

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to explicitly change the colours?

Comment: I was initially using this UIButton.Appearance.BackgroundColor = profileColor; but I think I can get all of this to work by not using the Appearance classes in the first place. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: AMI289, I got this working by not using the UIAppearance classes in the first place. So I never quite figured it out, but working another way. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`UIAppearance` isn't going to work right for you on `UIImagePickerController` (at least as of iOS 8.1). Same goes for a lot of built-in controllers, like the email one, etc.

In order to do what you need, there is an option to completely replace the UI on the camera. Then you can style it however you wish. Basically set `ShowsCameraControls` to false and add your own views, there are methods for changing the flash and starting the camera you can call programmatically.

It's definitely more work, but probably your only option.

Comment: I got this working - but not using UIAppearance for global settings in the first place. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.